# Sass Error: Illegal nesting

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, gulp-sass

Всем привет, есть ошибка:

```
Error: Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties.
        on line 4 of dist/sass/_test.sass
>>     @media screen and (max-width: $break_s1920) {

   ----^
```

Вот код неработающий (**даже если поместить его в отдельный файл**):

```
$break_s1920: 1920px

=s1920-block()
  @media screen and (max-width: $break_s1920)
    @content
```

Я пробовал и настройки **VS Code** менять, и переустановить его, переустановил **gulp-sass**, переписывал код (переменные впрорядку, миксины используются), даже винду сменил)
Самое смешное то, что этот код работает и весь остальной:

```
=s1680-block()
  @media screen and (max-width: $break_s1680)
    @content
```

Ошибка вылезла то внезапно. В VS Code использую **табы == 2 пробела**, в коде тоже так. Может ситнаксис поменялся, а документация Sass нет?) Или Vs Code настроить нужно как-то по особенному
Сделайте мне прямые руки, спасибо!

Comment: Sass Lint не помагает

Comment: в настройках изменены только табы на 2 пробела

Comment: Может проблема где-то выше? Но куда бы ты не ставил этот код у меня ошибка на месте

Comment: Если вынести код в отдельною папку и компилировать, то все хорошо.

Comment: Если у кого-то, есть предположения происхождения проблемы, то пишите...

Comment: gulp-sass работает хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перешол на SCSS поскольку времены нет, рекомендую тоже при подобных проблемах и их вобще не будет. А так то: поробуйте переписать код, удалить недавние плагины, сбросить настройки редактора, переустановить gulp-sass, node-sass.Если не помогло, смело переходите на SCSS поскольку это очень просто, немного синтаксис подучить.